# Send parameters to request Swift 3 Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hi I am new here and I got a problem with Swift 3 and Alamofire. I got to send this value exactly like it is, but I got an error. I think I should do that different way but I cant find it, could you help me?

> error: contextual type '[String : Any]' cannot be used with array
>   literal

```
let url: String = "http://192.168.1.1/ubus"
    let param: [String: Any] = ["{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"call\", \"params\": [ \"00000000000000000000000000000000\", \"session\", \"login\", { \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"admin01\"  } ] }" ]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if(response.result.isFailure){
                print("no data!");

            }else{
                print("received data!");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Print error pls

Comment: Use this array : let param: [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", [ "username": "root", "password": "admin01"]]]

Comment: Thank you a lot, really helped me!!

Comment: Any other issues ?

Comment: Remove all \ from param 
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", { "username": "root", "password": "admin01"  } ] }

Try this

Answer (score 2):

For solving of the issue try to understand how properly form params `Dictionary` for the request.

In you're case you have issue in params.

Fixed version:

```
let param: [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", [ "username": "root", "password": "admin01"]]]
```